# find difference between 2 text file in c

Tags: c

One condition in my code is not working. This condition is if first file becomes 4 lines and second file become 5 lines. Both files' first 4 lines are the same, but the second file's 5th line may be different or the same. My output must show "yes there is a different at 5th lines", but it's saying these files are identical. How can I fix this code?

**First file:**

```
one
two
three
four
```

**Second file:**

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

**My code:**

```
void diff(char* fileptr1, char* fileptr2)
{
  int maxlinelen=BUFF; //maximum line length buffer size

 /** string arrays pointers **/
  char *linebuffer1; 
  char *linebuffer2;      

  /** file pointers **/
  FILE *fp1;
  FILE *fp2;

  int line=0;    //line counter
  int counter=0; //identical flag

  linebuffer1=(char*)malloc(maxlinelen * sizeof(char*)); //memory allocation for linebuffers
  linebuffer2=(char*)malloc(maxlinelen * sizeof(char*));

  if((linebuffer1==NULL) || (linebuffer2==NULL))   //check memory allocating process
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"Command:diff :Memory allocating failed!\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  if(((fp1=fopen(fileptr1,"r"))!=NULL)&&((fp2=fopen(fileptr2,"r"))!=NULL))  //make sure both files open?
    {
      //read both files lines till end of line
      while(((fgets(linebuffer1,maxlinelen,fp1))!=NULL)&&((fgets(linebuffer2,maxlinelen,fp2))!=NULL)) 
    {
      while(strlen(linebuffer1)==maxlinelen-1) // perfect time for memory reallocating
        {
          maxlinelen*=DOUBLE;  //grow size
          linebuffer1=realloc(linebuffer1,maxlinelen * sizeof(char)); //reallocate memory to new size
          if(linebuffer1==NULL) //make sure allocation is succesfull
        {
          fprintf(stderr,"Command : diff :Memory reallocating failed for linebuffer1\n");
          exit(1);
        }
          fgets(linebuffer1+(maxlinelen/DIV-1),(maxlinelen/DIV)+1,fp1); //continue read line after reallocation
        }
      while(strlen(linebuffer2)==maxlinelen-1)
      {
        maxlinelen*=DOUBLE;
        linebuffer2=realloc(linebuffer2,maxlinelen * sizeof(char));
        if(linebuffer2==NULL)
          {
        fprintf(stderr,"Memory reallocating failed for linebuffer2\n");
        exit(2);
          }
        fgets(linebuffer2+(maxlinelen/DIV-1),(maxlinelen/DIV)+1,fp2);  //
      }
      line++;  //increae line counter


      if(strcmp(linebuffer1,linebuffer2)!=0)  //compare both line string arrays if not
             {
           printf("The files are different.The first difference is in line %d\n",line); //diff. here 
           exit(1);
         }

      if(strcmp(linebuffer1,linebuffer2)==0) //compare both line string arrays if same
             {
           counter++; //increase identical counter
         }
    }
      if(counter==line) //if identical counter equal total line
    {
      printf("The files are identical.\n");
    }
    }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Command: diff :File  open failed!\n");

 }

  //fclose(fp1);fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like you're asking someone to do your CompSci homework question.

Comment: My biggest peeve is when indentation is all funked up.

Comment: @Warren P i dont wanna whole code from u. just an idea. Thank u for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

here,you are using "&&" for the two file's fgets result.
So when either file reaches EOF the compare is over.

Your 5th line will never be compared.

```
while(((fgets(linebuffer1,maxlinelen,fp1))!=NULL)&&((fgets(linebuffer2,maxlinelen,fp2))!=NULL)
```

change this while loop condition and modify relative logic would help you correct your code.

Comment: ok thank u. I know problem here but i couldn't figure out how can i modify this line. is may be another while?

Comment: using a flag in your while loop. when the flag is true continue to compare the lines even if one of them is NULL. when both file end set the flag to be false. @ccc

Answer (score 0):

I believe your exit comparison for the read file loop fails when either file ends. That leads to you not reading the last line in a file, and thus incrementing the line counter variable.

You will need helper vars to record the result of the fgets for each line.

Comment: its like another 2 arrays? and compare all elements?